# Java return array from class

Tags: java, arrays, class

So I have 2 classes that I use:

```
public class Vote {

      public String vote;

       public Vote(String vote) {
            this.vote = vote;
        }

        public String getvote() {
            return vote;
        }
}
```

And then the other one that returns votes array:

```
public class Campaign {

    private String title;
    private Vote[] votes;

    public Campaign(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Vote[] getvotes() {
        return votes;
    }
    }
```

And in main im using this code:

```
public class maintest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Campaign first= new Campaign("test");
    Vote pvote = new Vote("vote1222");
    System.out.println(first.getTitle() + " " + " " + first.getvotes());
}
}
```

In the end I get value null. However I want to get "vote1222" also if I add more campaigns i want to retrieve more votes as well.

Comment: You did not add `pVote` to the array in `first` Campaign. Also mind that you'll probably want to use Arrays.toString to print out votes (and override toString in `Votes`).

Comment: what do you mean? ..

Comment: You created `first` Campaign and you created a Vote `pvote`. How do you think `first` knows anything about `pvote`?

Comment: Also there is no way to add votes to the Campaign as it is now.

Comment: in Campaign I'm using Vote[] class as array?

Comment: Since you didn't initialize `votes` `getvotes()` is bound to return `null` - no surprise here. What would you expect to happen? The vote doesn't automagically initialize the campaign's array and add itself to it.

Comment: "in Campaign I'm using Vote[] class as array?" - That only means you have a place, where you *could* save references to `Vote`s. But you don't. You don't even *create* the array, you only declare a variable that is supposed to reference one. I suggest you go through a basic tutorial about arrays (and variables, ... ) For example here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a setter in your `Campaign` class:

```
public void setVotes(Vote[] votes) {
    this.votes = votes;
}
```

In your `main` you must invoke this method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Campaign first= new Campaign("test");
    Vote pvote = new Vote("vote1222");
    Vote[] votes = new Vote[] { pvote };
    first.setVotes(votes);
    System.out.println(first.getTitle() + " " + " " + Arrays.toString(first.getvotes()));
}
```

As you can read in the comments, you should use `Arrays.toString`.

Thanks to Fildur: in `Vote` you need to overwrite `toString`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return vote;
}
```

Comment: Additionally, if it is supposed to print out the values of the Votes, `Vote` also needs to override `toString` returning its value.

Answer (score 1):

You should be better of not using arrays but collections, consider the fact that you dont know how many people will vote in advance...

to the issue:

vote is never initialized in the constructor, therefore null by printing the object, do instead...

```
private List<Vote> votes;

public Campaign(String title) {
    this.title = title;
    this.votes = new ArrayList<Vote>();
}
```

and then

```
public void addVote(Vote v) {
    this.votes.add(v);
}


public List<Vote> getvotes() {
    return votes;
}
```

and the implementation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Campaign first= new Campaign("test");
    Vote pvote = new Vote("vote1222");
    first.addVote(pvote);
    System.out.println(first.getTitle() + " " + " " + first.getvotes());
}
```

## Edit:

dont forget to override the toString method in the Vote class :)

Comment: Wouldn't this still only print a list of the object ids of the `Vote` list members? It is List<Vote>, not List<String> ...

Comment: yes, you need to override toString in the Vote class :)